# Select every 3 consecutive elements from an array and comparing them using a function

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// function to compare the three values
int maximum(int x, int y, int z) 
{
    int max;
    if (x > y) {
        max = x;
        if (z > max)
            max = z;

    } else {
        max = y;
        if (z > max)
            max = z;

    }
    return max;
}  
// main code

int main() {

    int i, a, b;
    cout << "La dimension de la table?" << endl; 

    // Ask user to select the size of the array, maximum 20. "a" is the size 
    cin >> a;
    while (a > 20) {
        cout << "La dimension maximum est 20! Reessayez!" << endl;
        cin >> a;
    }

    int v1[a];

    // ask user to fill the array
    cout << "Remplisez la table" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i = i + 1) {
        cin >> v1[i];
    }
    // using this variable to know when the loop should stop
    b = 0; 
    // selecting the 3 consecutive elements to compare
    while (b <= a) {
        for (i = b; i < 4; i = i + 1) { 
         // this is were it should compare the 3 selected values and print them
            cout << "Le maximum est " << maximum(v1[i], v1[i], v1[i]) << endl; 
        }
        // passing to the next 3 values

        b = b + 3; 
    }
}
```

This is my complete code. Everything works just fine except the last part where I have to select the values somehow and send them to the function to be compared. Any sugestions?

Thanks alot!

Comment: What do you mean by "everything works fine" ? which part is that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,

Your logic is correct for the most part. Having said that, I have some comments as follows:

You are creating a dynamic array as if it is a fixed size array:

```
int v1[a];
```

This array should be defined as follows:

```
int* v1 = int[a];
```

since the size is not known during the compile time. Therefore you need to allocate memory in the heap in runtime. Another option is using std::vector as Chris suggested.

AND

You are sending the same value to the function in all three arguments in your function call:

```
maximum(v1[i], v1[i], v1[i]);
```

which is a minor typo but would give erroneous results.

AND

You do not need nested loops for picking every three elements and sending them to the function.

Try:

```
b=0;
while(b <= (a-3))
{
    maximum(v1[b], v1[b+1], v1[b+2]);
    b+=3;
}
```

Here b needs to iterate until a-3 since the last three elements will start from that point.

Lastly, you can shorten your function as follows:

```
int maximum(int x, int y, int z) {
    int max=x;
    if(y>max) max=y;
    if(z>max) max=z;
    return max;
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Or `std::vector` so you don't have any memory leak worries. And can pass it into a function without an accompanying size.

Comment: The thing is that we have to use only what we saw in class. And nobody told us anything about dinamic arrays yet...But the problem comes when I try to select the first consecutive elements, the next 3 and so on.

Comment: Hey Alex. If you need to read the size of the array from the console during runtime you have to either use dynamic array or std::vector. Did you learn vector in class?

Comment: No we didn't. Just simple arrays. Another question:
What is the difference between b=b+3 and b+=3?

Comment: no difference between b=b+3 and b+=3. They are the same while the latter is shorter.

Comment: @AlexAnghel good to hear that. Upvote and/or check ok is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to compare every element in the array in groups of 3.  To accomplish that use

```
for (int i=0; i+2<a; i+=3)
   cout << "Le maximum est " << maximum(v1[i], v1[i+1], v1[i+2]) << endl;
```

Comment: Not a very good idea. Suppose I give you an array of one element.

Comment: I don't think this accomplishes the goal. It says _select **every** 3 consecutive elements_. This grabs 3 at a time but not every 3 consecutive group (i.e., it will grab 0, 1, and 2 but not 1, 2, and 3).

Comment: @JamesAdkison, Not according to the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482646/select-every-3-consecutive-elements-from-an-array-and-comparing-them-using-a-fun#comment47125868_29482646) (which should have been edited into the question, really).

Comment: @chris Okay, I see that now. Thanks.

Comment: James is right. It only works for the first 6 elements. If I want to make the array bigger it wont compare the next ones...